# React essence stylesheet is 14mb with webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, less, webpack, essence

I just recognized that my stylesheet is 14mb when I am using the react essence library for the UI part. Webpack is also using forever to bundle in the beginning.

I just tested this with a simple react app where I import just the essence button. The stylesheet appears to be 7mb. It looks like webpack is importing everything instead of parts.

My webpack config file is simple:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
        devtool: 'eval',
        entry: [
                'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
                './src/index.jsx'
        ],
        output: {
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'static'),
                filename: 'bundle.js',
                publicPath: '/static/'
        },
        plugins: [
                new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
                new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css', { allChunks: true }),
                new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
                     new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                        'process.env':{
                                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('devolopment')
                        }
                        })
                ],
        module: {
                loaders: [
                        {
                                test: /\.(jsx|js)/,
                                loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
                                resolve: ['.js', '.jsx'],
                                exclude: /node_modules/,
                                include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
                        },
                        {
                                test: /(\.css|.less)$/,
                                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!less-loader'),
                                resolve:['.less', '.css']
                        },
                        {
                                test: /\.(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff)/,
                                loader: 'url-loader'
                        }
                ]
        },
        resolve: {
                extensions: ['', '.js', '.json', '.less', '.jsx']
        }
};
```

What is the problem and how do I solve this?

**Edit**:

The webpack output when importing button from react-essence: [Link](http://hastebin.com/huxugamivo.pas)

The webpack out when importing button from essence-button: [Link](http://hastebin.com/videviyeni.pas)

Comment: How you importing button `import Btn from 'essence-button';` or `import { Btn as Btn } from 'essence';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Essence component import there are 2 options:

1. `import { Btn } from react-essence` will import all Essence css.
2. `import Btn from essence-btn` will import only the Essence Btn css & Essence core.

Will help me to solve this issue if you can share your code snippet so I can test/debug it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.You can find everything at my git.https://github.com/onurmhb/essenceTest

Comment: You're right importing btn from essence-button only imports the button. The stylesheet is still 7.68mb, but robofont is using 99% of it. So it is just the font then?

Comment: Yes, the `import Btn from 'essence-button';` does reduce the size to half. But the issue is on the components where LESS styling is imported. Let me update the components LESS style, do some tests and get back with you.

Comment: I'd updated all the components LESS files with `@import (reference)` which is an option in LESS for de-duplicating CSS styles. All the components are live on NPM so you can install them directly with `npm install ` and the name of the component.